# Edit Javascript of a website before the page is loaded Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am trying to make a chrome extension that can edit and remove parts of Javascript of a webpage preferably before the page is loaded.

For Example, the following script tag is within my test html website.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
function onchange(){
    console.log('left');
}
</script>
```

This code tells the console when the user switches tabs. I would like to be able to edit this specific code only to prevent this from happening. Can I modify the text of JavaScript before runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You cant modify the code before runtime but you can [remove the event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

```js
removeEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
```

Note: You technically *can* edit JS before it's executed in Chrome using [LocalOverrides](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides) however it requires you to have your devtools open on page load.

Comment: Good suggestion but when I run it within the extension, it has no effect on the website, I assume it's because it can't access the onchange function. Any advice? Would it be possible just to edit the html text directly?

Comment: See [page context](/a/9517879), but there's probably a better solution: add your own listener (without using the page context trick) with `true` for the third param of addEventListener, then call event.stopPropagation().